# Redirecting to error pages when there is no errors occurring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

This is quite complicated to explain.

I have an MVC C# razor website. I have enabled custom errors.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
    <error redirect="~/Error/404" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="~/Error/500" statusCode="500" />
</customErrors>
```

I load data based on ID passed in a query string e.g.

> www.website.com/default?id=0000-00000-00000

When I pass an ID which returns a huge amount of data, I get taken to the 500 error page.

I've stepped through the code, no exceptions are thrown. I even debug the view and I get to the bottom of the page, all is well but then the 500 error page is still returned.

When I comment out the custom errors in the config, I return to the expected page (not the error page) and all data is there that I am expecting.

Why would this be happening if I have no errors?

Comment: is there an entry in the event log giving you more information about the 500 error?

Comment: put your customError mode to Off, then the real error will be shown, post the error

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply @paul I forgot to mention I'm a novice! How do I get tot the event log?

Comment: @ChrisHall start menu -> event viewer -> windows logs

Comment: @anand I don't get one when I turn off custom errors!

Comment: on off mode you can print all data

Comment: @anand yes! And I log every time I handle an exception and there is nothing in my logs

Comment: you are handling an exception

Comment: @paul I looks like I was getting an out of memory exception, still don't understand why the website would work with custom errors off. Very strange! Thanks guys! Looks like I've got some refactoring to do haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in the logs, suggested by Paul, I was getting an out of memory exception.

My code always completed fully without breaking, but as an exception was hit at some point, I was returned to the error page.

I think this exception hit in some of the logic on the "cshtml" view page.